# Updating Room entitity and observing the list

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Imagine a list of posts (like Facebook) being presented to you in the Main Activity. The underlying "single source of truth" is the Database and Android's Room is used to fetch **and observe** this list of Posts.

This is how I'm observing the data (details omitted due to license issues and brevity):

```
faViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(FAViewModel.class);

faViewModel.getAllPosts().observe(getActivity(),
    newPosts - > {

        if (newPosts != null && newPosts.size() > 0) {
            postsLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        //  if ((posts == null) || newPosts.get(0).getId() != posts.get(0).getId()) {
        // Update the cached copy of the posts in the adapter.
        posts = newPosts;
        mPostsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager(), newPosts);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPostsAdapter);
        //                    }

    });

faViewModel.fetchNextData(currentPage);
```

Now, you also have a like button attached to every post, as well as the total number of likes a single post has received.

Now, the user clicks on the like button and you dispatch an action. This action can do the following:

1.1 Issue an update query that **increments the number of likes** a post has gotten.

1.2 Mark that this particular post in the database has been **liked by the user.**

2. Actually send a **POST request to the server** and update the artifacts there. (Total likes and posts this user has liked, among other things.)

Step 2 is doable so let's not talk about it. However, Step 1.1 and 1.2 are tricky because, when I issue my update query:

```
    @Query("UPDATE post SET liked= :liked, likes = likes + 1 WHERE id= :id")
    void updateLike(int id, int liked);
```

(Note: This doesn't care about dislikes. It works like medium. A user can give N likes to one post.)

Anyway, when I issue that query, it updates the database. Since, I'm actually **observing this database using `LiveData`**, I receive a new LiveData entity which I then attach to my adapter. My adapter thinks (and is right in thinking) that the **dataset has changed**, and hence it **updates** the list. While doing this, it also **scrolls to the first post in the list.** **THIS IS THE PROBLEM**.

How can I prevent that?

One possible solution is to check if the post id's of the incoming list and the current list are same, do not update. However, this means I won't get the updated `No of likes` and other things from the DB. This would in turn mean that when a user clicks on the like button, I'll manually have to change the `No of likes` and the Like drawable's state **IN THE VIEW**.

Is this the correct approach? Or is there something I can do to still have my database as the "*single source of truth*" while still having the Like Button facility.

Any other *ideas/hacks* are appreciated.

Comment: `I'm actually observing this database using LiveData` how are you observing `database` share code as well.

Comment: @AbdulKawee Updated the question with the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DiffUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) to solve your problem, if you are using a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, which means you have either a `RecyclerView` or a `ViewPager2`.

First you should not recreate the adapter each time the db emits new data.

When new data is available, you can use `DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffUtil.Callback cb)` to get a `DiffUtil.DiffResult` object, and then call `dispatchUpdatesTo(Adapter adapter)` on the result.

This way all the changes between old and new data will be applied individually. For instance, say your old list is `A,B,C`, if the new list is `A,X,B,C` then only `X` will be added to the RecyclerView (by default even with an animation).

Here's a sample implementation:

```
class ListDiffCalculator : DiffUtil.Callback() {

    private var oldList = emptyList<MyModel>()
    private var newList = emptyList<MyModel>()

    fun computeDiff(oldList: List<MyModel>, newList: List<MyModel>): DiffUtil.DiffResult {
        this.oldList = oldList
        this.newList = newList
        return DiffUtil.calculateDiff(this)
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
        oldList[oldItemPosition].id == newList[newItemPosition].id

    override fun getOldListSize() = oldList.size

    override fun getNewListSize() = newList.size

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
        oldList[oldItemPosition].hashCode() == newList[newItemPosition].hashCode()
}
```

Your Adapter can implement `Observer<List<MyModel>>` so that you can make it directly observe the db, omitting the other Adapter stuff here for simplicity:

```
class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>(), Observer<List<MyModel>> {

    private var data = emptyList<MyData>()  

    override fun onChanged(newData: List<MyModel>?) {
        newData?.let {
            val diff = listDiffCalculator.computeDiff(data, newData)
            this.data = newData
            diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
        }
    }
}
```

And observe:

```
aViewModel.getAllPosts().observe(getActivity(), adapter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @lelloman. However, can I use DiffUtil with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter + ViewPager?

Comment: I don't think so, I thought you were using a recycler view xD With [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) you can though. The problem is that RecyclerView.Adapter has methods to notify specific changes instead of just `notifyDatasetChanged`.

Comment: Oh, nice. But that's still in alpha and I'll never get approval for using it in production right now :P Thanks for your answer. Really helpful for future readers.

Comment: Yeah you should not use it right now in production :D but still, PagerAdapter doesn't have the API to notify individual changes so you will have to hack your way through it.

Comment: Right. Cool, I think I'll sort of implement the hack I had mentioned in the question. Will come back to this answer if we ever have a chance to move to a RecyclerView or ViewPager2. :) Thanks!